# Disable all types of optimizations in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How should you disable all types of optimizations while debugging in VS2010?

Comment: yes, this is usually automatic in a debug configuration

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To insure optimizations are off, right click on your project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization -> Optimization = Disabled. This is the /Od compiler switch.

Answer (score 4):

Select the menu item `Project->Properties`.

Under `Configuration Properties->C/C++->Optimization`, in the `Optimization` field, select `disabled`.

Answer (score 2):

There should be none or at least less optimization going on in a debug build. Check your buildsettings for more options.

Answer (score 2):

Add -O0 to compiler parameters. This should turn off all optimizations.

Comment: I believe that /Od is equivalent to /O0.

Comment: Yes, it's /Od on Windows. -O0 is GCC.

Answer (score -2):

Go to your project, right click on it → **Properties** → **Build** → (go down and click on) **Advanced** → a window will opened and check whether **Debug info** in **Output** is **Full**.