# Identifier "(variable)" is undefined

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am doing debug of my program, but in VS2010 `cnt` is defined without any problems (same code). In VS2013 `cnt` is "undefined" which will result in a malfunction of the program. Any idea why?

```
int
adin_file_read(SP16 *buf, int sampnum)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int cnt = 0; //nº de bytes lido numa evocação da função adin_file_read
    fp = gfp;
    //sum_samples --> nº total de bytes lidos
    //global_size --> nº total de bytes do buffer de audio

    //Se é um ficheiro wav
    if (wav_p) {
        cnt = fread(buf, sizeof(SP16), sampnum, fp);
        if (cnt == 0) {
            if (feof(fp)) return -1; /* EOF */
            if (ferror(fp)) {
                jlog("Error: adin_file: an error occured while reading file\n");
                adin_file_close();
                return -2; /* error */
            }
        }
        if (nowlen + cnt > maxlen) {
            cnt = maxlen - nowlen;
        }
        nowlen += cnt;
    }
    else {  //Se é um RAW FILE
        //AXY5
        if (has_pre) {
            int i;
            has_pre = FALSE;

            for (i = 0; i <= sampnum; i++){
                if (i > global_size / sizeof(SP16)) {
                    cnt = i;
                    sum_samples = i;
                    break;
                }
                buf[i] = real_data[i];
            }

            if (cnt == 0) {
                if (sum_samples > global_size / sizeof(SP16)){
                    return -1;
                }
            } (.....continue).. return cnt;
```

[image: vs2013 behavior]

Comment: You should rather be sorry about the screenshot. Please copy-and-paste the code into the question as text.

Comment: *Where* do you get the error?

Comment: The objective was to show the behavior of visual studio. @MOehm Sorry about that to

Comment: I have no errors, but because `cnt` apparently is not defined the final result will not be the correct.

Comment: @jdscardoso Isn't that an error ?

Comment: @ameyCU yes, at least from the compiler since the code is the same.

Comment: Ah, it's an error in the debugger, that the debugger can't find the variable. This is often the case if the variable have been optimized away for some reason. Try disabling *all* optimizations and try again.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. As it is, I must condede that the image did indeed include important information for Visual Studio users. I'm sorry.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This options was already previously selected. But thanks for the tip

Comment: But the screenshot shows a breakpoint at a spot where the value of `cnt` is not significant. To make your question more valid you really need to show a breakpoint at the first point where `cnt` is actually used. If it is still undefined at that point then you may have something to worry about. As it is, it is not clear whether this is just a debugging artifact or whether something really has gone wrong.

Comment: [unrelated] suspect: `for (i = 0; i <= sampnum; i++){` -->> `for (i = 0; i < sampnum; i++){` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tip of @JoachimPileborg the problem was solved.
The instructions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707384/disable-all-types-of-optimizations-in-vs2010) and after doing that I restarted the VS2013, and now is working.